# Transition matrix for barbershop problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A small barbershop, operated by a single barber, has room for at most two customers. Customers leave if the shop is full when they arrive. Potential customers arrive at a Poisson process with rate of three per hour, and the successive service times are independent exponential random variables with an average of fifteen minutes.
>
> Question: If there are two barbers, where each barber needs a length of time that is exponentially distributed with an average of fifteen minutes for service, how many customers are served per hour?

This is a birth-and-death (BD) process.
In the case there is only one barber, the transition matrix is given by

$Q = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 3 & 0 \\ 4 &-7&3 \\ 0&4&-4 \end{pmatrix}$, so the the birth rates are $\lambda = 3$ and the death rates are $\mu = 4$.

But what is $Q$ for the two barbers case? $\lambda$ does not change since the customers arrive is the same, but what about $\mu$? If I know this, I can find the the steady-state probabilities and find an answer to the question.